# What effect do the 'wherein' and 'further comprising' clauses have in this Microsoft brain-computer interface patent claim?

Tags: patent-applications

Microsoft recently [filed a claim](http://patft1.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PALL&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsrchnum.htm&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=9864431.PN.&OS=PN/9864431&RS=PN/9864431) relating to brain-computer interfaces.

Claim 1 sets out the basic 'invention', and other claims following using 'whereby' and 'further comprising' seem to specify certain details about it.

Is the patent claim therefore an attempt to patent not just claim 1 with regard to the other claims but also claim 1 in itself?

Would claim 1 be infringed only if all of the following claims were also infringed?

Would claim 1 be infringed if only one or some of the following claims were also infringed?

Would claim 1 be infringed if none of the following claims were also infringed?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a lawyer, but to infringe on a patent, you need only infringe on a single claim. Thus if you implement every feature of claim 1 that alone is sufficient to constitute infringement. You don't need to infringe on any dependent claim of claim 1 to infringe claim 1. Each claim stands alone except that dependent claims include, by reference, the text of the claims or chain of claims they depend from.